# fabricjs make from canvas to image

Tags: css, html, canvas, fabricjs

I have differents backgrounds types (box, rounded, oval). So when i choose type rounded, for example, it looks like this:[image: this]

example of css for this form:

```
element.style {
    border-radius: 437px/437px !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 874px;
    height: 874px;
}
```

But when i try to convert this in png, like this:

```
function download(url,name){
// make the link. set the href and download. emulate dom click
            $('<a>').attr({href:url,download:name})[0].click();
        }
        $("#canvas-to-png").click(function(){
            // to PNG
            //window.open(canvas.toDataURL('png'), '_blank');
            download(canvas.toDataURL(), 'canvas' + '.png');
        });
```

Downloaded file looks like this(Edges become visible):
[image]

How i can make png file looks as first screen (Save edges)?
Cheers!

Comment: Did you change your canvas to be rounded using CSS?

Comment: @Observer yes. I was change css

Comment: Don't change the style of the canvas. Put inside fabric object as you need (circle, oval, etc.) and do your logic what you want for download.